# Animated series/movie 70s or 80s involving aliens impersonating humans and guy looking for missing girl/sister

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I don’t remember much but the few things still in my memory are:
There were aliens or some other kind of creatures that were looking like humans and when they die they turn into real form.
Main character: 
a guy  that maybe was able to sense them or even see through disguise
he was looking for his sister or girl that was found on other planet under water (sea or ocean) there were also city ruins of human or alien origin  and people turned to statues of some kind or they were in stasis pods. 
Maybe it was French or Belgium 2 part movie but big maybe. I watched in 80s or very early 90s.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: It sounds like cocoon, there is also cocoon 2.